# What is /sbin/zonename ? Where do I get it for CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

What is /sbin/zonename ? Where do I get it for CentOS?

I am trying to use puppet  (system administration), and it can't find this command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

yum whatprovides '*bin/zonename'

but our Puppet installs run just fine without it.  Are you using the puppet package from EPEL?  You'll also want facter from EPEL.

Assuming CentOS 5.x (cat /etc/redhat-release) and an x86_64 architecture (uname -a), after deleting any version of Puppet you installed outside of RPM, just do:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
yum install puppet facter
```

And that should sort you out nicely.  If it doesn't, can you give us the exact error message you're getting, and where and when you're seeing it?

Comment: I got it worked out. I was originally building everything from source. EPEL was definitely much easier :)

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken, [zonename](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/zonename-1.html#scrolltoc) is used on Solaris to identify the current local [zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers).

I don't believe that there is a CentOs equivalent, because CentOS does not use Solaris zones.